# Bash : date -d throws "invalid date" when date is parameterized

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

When I parameterize the date in the code as :

```
str_last_log_date="2017-07-24"
last_log_date=$(date -d '${str_last_log_date}' +%s)
threshold_days_ago=$(date -d 'now - 2 days' +%s)
echo "last_log_date ${last_log_date}  thres_days_ago ${threshold_days_ago}"
```

Gives the error :

> date: invalid date ‘${str_last_log_date}’ 
>   last_log_date thres_days_ago 1500969455

But if I don't parameterize the date and pass directly, it gives the correct result :

```
last_log_date=$(date -d '2017-07-24' +%s)
threshold_days_ago=$(date -d 'now - 2 days' +%s)
echo "last_log_date ${last_log_date}  thres_days_ago ${threshold_days_ago}"
```

> last_log_date 1500854400  thres_days_ago 1500969511

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
last_log_date=$(date -d '${str_last_log_date}' +%s)
```

Should be updated to be (remove single quotes):

```
last_log_date=$(date -d ${str_last_log_date} +%s)
```

Comment: better yet, replace the single-quotes with double-quotes, so that it still works if $last_log_date is changed to contain a space (like "2017-07-24 21:16:00").  more re-usable too.

Comment: @cas, or `$IFS` is modified to include `-` or `:` or digits...

Comment: and, of course, the many other reasons why it's a [good idea to always quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Answer (score 8):

Variables are not expanded when put inside single quotes; use double quotes instead:

```
date -d "${str_last_log_date}"
```